# Using Async/Await on multiple settimeout

Tags: javascript, async-await

To understand async/await, I am trying to display a console message once settimeout runs and expires. How do I fix my code below? I have 5 settimeout function and each should display respective message once finished.

```js
function t1(){
    setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("1")
    }, 1000);
}

function t2(){
    setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("2")
    }, 2000);
}

function t3(){
    setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("3")
    }, 3000);
}

function t4(){
    setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("4")
    }, 4000);
}

function t5(){
    setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("5")
    }, 5000);
}

async function main(){
    await t1();
    console.log("1sec done");
    await t2();
    console.log("2sec done");
    await t3();
    console.log("3sec done");
    await t4();
    console.log("4sec done");
    await t5();
    console.log("Yay! I am all done");
}
main();
```

Comment: async-await is for promises.

Answer (score 4):

You should use [Promises](https://learn.javascript.ru/promise)

```js
function t1(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("1");
        resolve();
      }, 1000);
   });
}

function t2(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("2");
        resolve();
      }, 1000);
   });
}

function t3(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("3");
        resolve();
      }, 1000);
   });
}

function t4(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("4");
        resolve();
      }, 1000);
   });
}

function t5(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("5");
        resolve();
      }, 1000);
   });
}

async function main(){
    await t1();
    console.log("1sec done");
    await t2();
    console.log("2sec done");
    await t3();
    console.log("3sec done");
    await t4();
    console.log("4sec done");
    await t5();
    console.log("Yay! I am all done");
}
main();
```

Answer (score 2):

You are doing two mistakes

- First you are using `await` before a calling a function `t1,t2,t3...`. `await` should be used on **Promises**.
- You are passing `1000,2000,...` to `setTimeout()`. You should create a function which returns a `Promise` which will be resolved after 1 second
- Use `await` before the promise returned by that function

```js
let afterOne = (num) => new Promise(res => {
    setTimeout(()=>{
      //log the number passed to function after 1000 ms
      console.log(num);
      //resolve the current promise so then next setTimeout could be set
      res();
   },1000)
  })
async function main(){
    /*This loop does same as
       await afterOne(0);
       await afterOne(1);
       await afterOne(2)
       await afterOne(3);
       await afterOne(4);
    */
    for(let i = 0;i<5;i++){
      await afterOne(i)
    }
}
main();
```

Answer (score 1):

For each of the functions `t1()` through `t5()`, you'll need to ensure these return a `Promise` such that the returned promise is "resolved" once the respective `setTimeout()` timer inside has completed.

By returning the `Promise` object in this way, your `t1()` -> `t5()` functions effectivly become `async` methods, which in turn means than the `await` prefix will cause execution of `main()` to block until each `t1()` -> `t5()` function has completed (or "been resolved").

To illustrate this, consider the following code where a generic `delay()` function replaces the `t1()` -> `t5()` functions in your original code:

```js
/* I've defined a generic delay function as replacement
for t1 - t5 functions to minimise the amount of code */
function delay(seconds) {

  /* Return a promise object that will cause the
  await to prevent main() async function's execution
  from continuing until this promise has resolved */
  return (new Promise((resolve) => {

    /* Inside the promise, set your time out */
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(seconds)

      /* When time out complete, call resolve(), which
      resolves this promise and allows main() async 
      function's execution to continue */
      resolve()
    }, seconds * 1000);

  }))

}

async function main() {
  await delay(1);
  console.log("1sec done");
  await delay(2);
  console.log("2sec done");
  await delay(3);
  console.log("3sec done");
  await delay(4);
  console.log("4sec done");
  await delay(5);
  console.log("Yay! I am all done");
}
main();
```

Comment: I have read that putting async before a function will make it return promise. So If I declare those t1-t5 functions like as `async function t1(){...}`, will it make any difference, as it will be returning promises also?

Comment: Putting `async` before your function declaration won't cause that function to automatically behave the way you're wanting it to here. Doing that basically means you are able to use the`await` keyword when calling other asynchronous functions from inside of the `t1()` function for instance - hope that helps 